# Grouping and replacing groups inside stream, Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping, collectors

I have such task: in sorted stream of Strings, change all groups of 3 same strings to one that contains a capital letter (use java 8 stream API). Example:

```
input = {"a","a","b","b","b","c"} 

output = {"a","a","B","c"}
```

I can count same Strings in stream but I don't understand how to replace a group, without extra iterations. All I have now is:

```
Map<String, Long> result = Stream.of("a","a","b","b","b","c")
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                    LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(result);
```

//current output: {a=2, b=3, c=1}

Comment: so if `b` occurred 4 times the output would just be `{"a","a","b","b","b","b","c"}` or `{"a","a","B","b","c"}`?

Comment: it will appear not more than 3 times, so it will be a capital letter

Answer (score 1):

> I can count same Strings in stream but I don't understand how to
>   replace a group, **without extra iterations**

if you're going to persist with the stream approach then you have no choice but to stream over the `entrySet()`.

The second thing I'd like to point out is that instead of using the `counting` collector it would be better to use the `toList` collector just to make life a little bit easier when we stream over the `entrySet` to perform further operations.

i.e.

```
 Stream.of("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c")
       .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        toList()))
       .entrySet().stream()
       .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().size() == 3 ? Stream.of(e.getKey().toUpperCase()) :
             e.getValue().stream())
       .collect(toList());
```

for completeness, if you want to persist with the `counting` collector then you can do:

```
Stream.of("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c")
      .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        counting()))
      .entrySet().stream()
      .flatMap(e -> e.getValue() == 3 ? Stream.of(e.getKey().toUpperCase()) :
                        Stream.generate(e::getKey).limit(e.getValue()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you could also replace `Stream.generate(e::getKey).limit(e.getValue())` with `LongStream.range(0, e.getValue()).mapToObj(s -> e.getKey())` if you wanted to...

Answer (score 0):

Collect to a List and rewind if you "see a triple".

```
List<String> coalesced = Stream.of("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c")
  .sequential()
  .collect(LinkedList::new, this::coalesce, List::addAll);
System.out.println(coalesced);

private void coalesce(LinkedList<String> list, String s) {
  if (s.equals(list.peekLast()) &&
      list.size() > 1 &&
      s.equals(list.get(list.size() - 2))) {
    list.removeLast();
    list.removeLast();
    list.add(s.toUpperCase());
  } else {
    list.add(s);
  }
}
```

Being a Collector, this is threadsafe though the below will work *only* for a single-threaded stream until `List::addAll` is replaced by something that is aware that a "triple" could span the two Lists.